# error to run a insert in auth_user

Tags: python, django

I have a table with fields related with the django's table called auth_user, i need to run a unitary test to test the **str** method about other entity of the models.py, but i when run the test, i get the next issue:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (key_process_indicator_bsc.unitary_test.test_models.ModelsTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializ
ers/json.py", line 79, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializ
ers/python.py", line 96, in Deserializer
    Model = _get_model(d["model"])
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializ
ers/python.py", line 166, in _get_model
    return apps.get_model(model_identifier)
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry
.py", line 201, in get_model
    app_label, model_name = app_label.split('.')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/testcase
s.py", line 956, in setUpClass
    'database': db_name,
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/manageme
nt/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
    return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/manageme
nt/base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/manageme
nt/commands/loaddata.py", line 60, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/manageme
nt/commands/loaddata.py", line 90, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/manageme
nt/commands/loaddata.py", line 141, in load_label
    for obj in objects:
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializ
ers/json.py", line 85, in Deserializer
    six.reraise(DeserializationError, DeserializationError(e), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py"
, line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializ
ers/json.py", line 79, in Deserializer
    for obj in PythonDeserializer(objects, **options):
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializ
ers/python.py", line 96, in Deserializer
    Model = _get_model(d["model"])
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/serializ
ers/python.py", line 166, in _get_model
    return apps.get_model(model_identifier)
  File "/home/leidyj/envs/key_process_indicator/key_process_indicator_bsc_local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry
.py", line 201, in get_model
    app_label, model_name = app_label.split('.')
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture '/home/leidyj/key_process_indicator_bsc_repository
/key_process_indicator_bsc/key_process_indicator_bsc/fixtures/test_data_key_process_indicator_bsc.json': need more than 1 value 
to unpack

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.113s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

the json file, that is my set data, has:

```
{"pk":1,
"model":"auth_user",
"fields":{
            "password":"pbkdf2_sha256$20000$PFQCunwR7Rzz$rhTeSCRUCz8hqwYGf8Uprj+B/5yAmYMzjc6jamY9eCw=",
            "last_login":"2015-12-30 14:17:39.413827",
            "is_superuser":1,
            "username":"admin",
            "first_name":"Leidy",
            "last_name":"Johanna",
            "email":"leidyj241@gmail.com",
            "is_staff":1,
            "is_active":1,
            "date_joined":"2015-12-30 14:17:29.150420"
         }

},

{"pk":1,
"model":"key_process_indicator_bsc.Indicator",
"fields":{
            "name":"indicator 1",
            "goal":100,
            "minimum_range":20,
            "hight_range":50,
            "weight":100,
            "acountable":1,
            "responsible":1,
            "indicator_type":1,
            "unite_measure":1,
            "created_at": "2015-11-11",
            "modified_at": "2015-11-11",
            "deleted": 0
         }

}
```

somebody that help me, thanks.

bye,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fixtures, you should have `auth.model` with a dot, not an underscore.

```
model": "auth.user",
```